# Why is there no combineLatest for kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

We had a situation where we combine a few flows and then make a network request, and noticed that the previous network request would not cancel on the combine receiving new values, it would rather wait for the previous run to finish.

To combat this we let the combine just associate all values in an intermediary object, and did collectLatest on the result of this transform. Now the network request will cancel on new values to the combine.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    combine()
    collectLatest()
}

@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
private fun combine() {
    println("Combine test")
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    fun log(string: String) = println("${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}    $string")

    suspend fun getCategories() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            log("getting categories off main thread, suspending")
            delay(100)
        }
    }

    val storeFlow = MutableStateFlow(0).apply { onEach { log("storeFlow set to $it") } }
    val shopLocalFlow = storeFlow.map {
        log("starting shopLocalFlow $it, suspending")
        delay(10)
        log("ending shopLocalFlow $it with value ${it * 10}")
        it * 10
    }
    val mainFlow = combine(storeFlow, shopLocalFlow) { store, shopLocal ->
        try {
            log("starting combine store=$store shopLocal=$shopLocal")
            getCategories()
            log("ending combine store=$store shopLocal=$shopLocal")
        } catch (e: CancellationException) {
            log("combine CANCELLED")
        }
    }
    mainFlow.launchIn(GlobalScope)
    runBlocking {
        storeFlow.value = 1
        log("runBlocking set store to 1, suspending")
        delay(200)
        storeFlow.value = 2
        log("runBlocking set store to 2, suspending")
        delay(200)
        mainFlow.first() // await finish
    }
}

@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
private fun collectLatest() {
    println("Collect latest test")
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    fun log(string: String) = println("${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}    $string")

    suspend fun getCategories() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            log("getting categories off main thread, suspending")
            delay(100)
        }
    }

    val storeFlow = MutableStateFlow(0).apply { onEach { log("storeFlow set to $it") } }
    val shopLocalFlow = storeFlow.map {
        log("starting shopLocalFlow $it, suspending")
        delay(10)
        log("ending shopLocalFlow $it with value ${it * 10}")
        it * 10
    }

    data class CombineWrapper(val store: Int, val shopLocal: Int)

    val mainFlow = combine(storeFlow, shopLocalFlow) { store, shopLocal ->
        log("creating combine wrapper")
        CombineWrapper(store, shopLocal)
    }
    GlobalScope.launch {
        mainFlow.collectLatest {
            try {
                log("starting collectLatest store=${it.store} shopLocal=${it.shopLocal}")
                getCategories()
                log("ending collectLatest store=${it.store} shopLocal=${it.shopLocal}")
            } catch (e: CancellationException) {
                log("collectLatest CANCELLED")
            }
        }
    }
    runBlocking {
        storeFlow.value = 1
        log("runBlocking set store to 1, suspending")
        delay(200)
        storeFlow.value = 2
        log("runBlocking set store to 2, suspending")
        delay(200)
    }
}
```

Output will be

```
Combine test
56    runBlocking set store to 1, suspending
71    starting shopLocalFlow 1, suspending
84    ending shopLocalFlow 1 with value 10
84    starting combine store=1 shopLocal=10
85    getting categories off main thread, suspending
190    ending combine store=1 shopLocal=10
262    runBlocking set store to 2, suspending
262    starting shopLocalFlow 2, suspending
262    starting combine store=2 shopLocal=10
262    getting categories off main thread, suspending
274    ending shopLocalFlow 2 with value 20
367    ending combine store=2 shopLocal=10
367    starting combine store=2 shopLocal=20
367    getting categories off main thread, suspending
469    starting shopLocalFlow 2, suspending
472    ending combine store=2 shopLocal=20
481    ending shopLocalFlow 2 with value 20
481    starting combine store=2 shopLocal=20
481    getting categories off main thread, suspending
586    ending combine store=2 shopLocal=20
Collect latest test
3    runBlocking set store to 1, suspending
9    starting shopLocalFlow 1, suspending
22    ending shopLocalFlow 1 with value 10
22    creating combine wrapper
23    starting collectLatest store=1 shopLocal=10
23    getting categories off main thread, suspending
129    ending collectLatest store=1 shopLocal=10
207    runBlocking set store to 2, suspending
207    starting shopLocalFlow 2, suspending
207    creating combine wrapper
208    starting collectLatest store=2 shopLocal=10
208    getting categories off main thread, suspending
220    ending shopLocalFlow 2 with value 20
220    creating combine wrapper
221    collectLatest CANCELLED
221    starting collectLatest store=2 shopLocal=20
222    getting categories off main thread, suspending
327    ending collectLatest store=2 shopLocal=20
```

I would think a combineLatest would exist to handle this, but it seems it does not?

Comment: Its not difficult to write our own combineLatest with the logic above, but maybe there is a reason it doesn't exist?

Comment: But why do we need `combineLatest()` if we have `combine()` and `collectLatest()`/`mapLatest()`? This is pretty much redundant.

Comment: Yeah, I know, we can say the same about `collectLatest()` and `mapLatest().collect()` or `flatMapMerge()` and `map().flattenMerge()`, but my point is: we generally prefer to chain multiple "smaller" operators, then using a single one doing multiple things. There are some "shortcuts" here and there, mostly because they are very common or are easier to understand, but they are exceptions from the above rule. Maybe `combineLatest()` is indeed a good candidate for a new operator.

Comment: You cant chain combine and collectLatest in a nice way that I am aware of

Comment: They do seem loathe to add operators at all, and `combineLatest` would not just be one, but six if you include overloads to match what `combine` has. And it would be 12 if you also did `combineTransformLatest`. I do agree `combine` kind of needs it because the workaround requires temporarily putting the arguments into a class just to pass them to the next operator.